# Go not running in terminal

Tags: go, cmd

For some reason now, when I try to run my Go code in command prompt my computer first asks me if I want to run this program "go.exe" from an unknown publisher.

Then once I hit yes, a separate window flashs open, I assume runs the program, then closes.

I have run different Go code before and never have had this happen to me.

Here is the simple go Hello World code saved under "test.go" located in my "C:\Users\\go\src\test\"

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello World!")
}
```

In the Command Prompt, I write `go run test.go`

Any Go command does the same thing. I can't even run `go version`

How do I get Go to run in the terminal without my computer asking me to run the program every time, and it opening a separate window that I cannot see the results?

Comment: It sounds like you're running into trouble with the "This file is from another computer" issue on Windows, which sounds odd to me. Have you tried right-clicking the `go.exe` file and selecting Properties to ensure that the "This file is from another computer" message doesn't appear? If it does, click the Unblock button next to it and apply the changes. This assumes you have the permissions to make this change, but if it's on your personal computer or in your user directory, you should be able to do this. If it doesn't appear, perhaps another "go" program in your PATH is executed instead.

Comment: Also from the command prompt, try `where go` to see the location of the `go.exe`. Does it match with where you installed it?

Comment: Thanks,  I found it under the Compatibility tab in Properties. It seems that "Run this program as an administrator" was checked. Once I unselected this it everything works now.